# Ribbon Toolbar and Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, user-interface, .net-3.5, ribbon

Today I was listening to the [Hanselminutes show about .NET 3.5 SP1...What's inside](http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=145), and they twice mentioned the Office 2007-like Ribbon control that is included in Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1.

I am very interested about this, as I was previously looking at purchasing this from a 3rd party vendor (likely [DevComponent's DotNetBar](http://www.devcomponents.com/dotnetbar/ribbon-control.aspx)).  However, I did some research this morning and have found nothing about this control being included for use with C# and WPF.  Does anyone know more about the included Ribbon control and whether or not it is available for C# or WPF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah I did a double-take when I heard them say that too.

The ribbon control, along with a DatePicker and DataGrid, are being developed out of band [over here](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf) on CodePlex. I'm not sure why Carl and Scott were suggesting that it was part of the SP1 release.

[Vincent Sibal](http://blogs.msdn.com/vinsibal/) posts about DataGrid (which is available already in some form) on his blog.

Comment: As of October, they've finally released a WPF Ribbon Preview!

Answer (score 4):

It was in VS 2008 as part of a C++/MFC update. I'm not sure about C#/WPF.

Answer (score 0):

A preview of the WPF Ribbon control was released last week, you can find [here](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview)

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to give a look at Phil Wright's excellent Krypton products range. It includes an excellent Ribbon component. (It's a WinForms component, not WPF).