# What is the Best WPF Ribbon Control Suite?

Tags: .net, wpf, wpf-controls, ribbon

I'm going to add a WPF Ribbon UI to my program.

What is the best suite of WPF controls including a ribbon control, based on your experiences?

Thanks!

Comment: `CodePlex` Archive will be shut down after July 1st, 2021. The link will be broken soon.

Answer (score 23):

Please, take a look at Fluent Ribbon Control Suite: http://fluent.codeplex.com

"Fluent Ribbon Control Suite is a library that implements an Office-like (Microsoft® Office Fluent™ user interface) for the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). It provides well-customized controls such as RibbonTabControl, Gallery, QuickAccessToolbar, ScreenTip, StatusBar and so on. It is bundled with the most up-to-date Office 2010 styles."

Comment: Note: DaVinci is the developer of the Fluent Ribbon Control Suite. However, I have been evaluating it, and I like it.

Comment: I just grabbed it and was up and going in five minutes because of the awesome walkthrough he wrote.

Comment: I can't use the visual designer with this

Comment: `CodePlex` Archive will be shut down after July 1st, 2021. The link is broken.

Answer (score 13):

I would recommend the [WPF Ribbon Preview](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf/Wiki/View.aspx?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview), since that's the one which will go into the next .NET release anyway.

Comment: Still too buggy to be used. I've managed to get it stuck in an infinite loop just by making the window narrow.

Comment: Correction. The bug I found only affects XP. On Windows 7 is works great.

Comment: This control is now released as a "final": http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en#Instructions

Comment: please note that it is actually a separate project, that does not really correspond to .NET releases.
Also they did remove the office-like styles that had been around in the preview.

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft released their updated WPF Ribbon on 8/2/10. Here is the link:

[Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en)

Comment: And now there is another update from 10/22/2010: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

I tried several products but stopped on [DevComponents](http://devcomponents.com/dotnetbar-wpf/wpfribbon/) implementation. Simple to use and yet very efficient. Check out the trial version and samples they provide. The price is also low enough.

Answer (score 1):

[SandRibbon](http://divelements.com/net/), best of all when you buy it, upgraded versions are free and the author constantly updates, improves & fixes (a new release almost weekly) and you can contact him directly, very smart guy and will accept any feedback.

He makes a version for web pages, Silverlight and Windows Applications with [live demos](http://divelements.com/net/controls/sandribbonsl/livedemofullscreen.htm) available.

Comment: SandRibbon has shown very little interest in fixing bugs in the WPF version, even when we provide comprehensive replication which they acknowledge.  I do not recommend them and after about 12 months of deployed usage we are now removing it from our application.

Comment: That's a shame, the SandRibbon author (whom I've talked to multiple times) is really smart.  My only guess is their WPF version isn't selling well so it's not worth the time to dedicate dev time to.

Comment: Not selling well? How about fixing up their bloody shit so it DOES sell well. Ofcourse it won't sell well if people have problems with it.