# WPF ribbon control

Tags: c#, wpf, open-source, controls, ribbon

Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474104/what-is-the-best-wpf-ribbon-control-suite) question from last year. I am checking two open source ribbon controls:

1. [Fluent](http://fluent.codeplex.com/)
2. [Odyssey](http://odyssey.codeplex.com/)

Do you have any experience (good or bad) with any of them? or perhaps know of another open source ribbon control?

---

**Follow up:**

After using both of them, I gave up `Odyssey` cause it had a lot of bugs. I then switched to `Fluent` and I have only good words to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trialling the WPF toolkit. Bear in mind - it's not open source per se - you don't get the source code. However, I believe it is free for use etc.

It's reasonably easy to use and has some reasonable commanding support. The documentation is not particularly in-depth, but it looks good - same as the ribbon used in Office 2007 etc. and has a few themes.

I'd say give it a look before spending money on a third party commercial ribbon control.

Answer (score 0):

there is one included in the [WPF toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Ribbon%20Preview) dont know how good/bad it it. we use one that we bought.