# Bought-in ribbon UI component experience with DotNet

Tags: c#, winforms, components

What is people's experience in using bought-in components for ribbon-based user interfaces in DotNet (specifically c#, though I imagine the components should be language agnostic like any other DotNet beastie). We're using VS 2008.

I've looked at other similar questions on Stack Overflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms), but I'm more interested in feedback from anyone who has actually used one or more third-party products, and for **Winforms** work, not C++/MFC.

In the past we've used TMS components with Delphi, but now we need ribbon support, preferably with glass capability. It looks like DotNetBar from DevComponents is a decent fit... does any one have experience with this or similar components? Ease of use, speed of bug fixes etc?

I know about the MS licence issue, so there's no need to discuss that. Just real-world experience please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used DevExpress

**PRO**

- It's very complete..
- All components (next to the ribbon) have a consistent look
  and feel AND behaviour
- Easy to use (winforms designer support very good)
- Not many bugs that I know of

**CON**

- All painting is done by .NET so it's a bit "heavy"
- The devexpress library is HUGE. Including the ribbon in your product automatically includes ate least 3 extra dll's of 500-1000Kb

Answer (score 0):

I am a [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com) user. I am currently working on a winforms project. I use their ribbon implementation and it hasn't failed me once.

One of the main benefits I see with this supplier is that they have a a decent documentation, large user base and many components (so your app doesn't have bits and blob from all over the world wide web). The ribbon does what ribbon should do, I see little rocket science there. I would even say that the glow you get when hovering over a ribbon's button is bit nicer than in the office suite. You also get the same rich tooltip's appearance as well.

DevExpress release fixes about once a month, but they aren't related to the ribbon very often.