# How do I create an attractive GUI in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface

How do I create an attractive GUI - similar to the one used for Microsoft Office - in C#?

I will be using Winforms and C#.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Comment: How about starting with some books on UX?

Comment: A generic question like this is quite useless. You could ask "is there anyway I can create a better car like the Ferrari?". You shoud begin designing your car and then watching who is doing the "right" component for your car. You can buy "controls", but you can't but "interfaces" (technically you can, but they won't solve all your problems). If you ask "what is the best grid for WPF", then THAT is an intelligent question. And then, Word is an editor. Are you doing an editor? Excel is a spreadsheet, are you doing a spreadsheet?

Comment: @xanatos: Presumably, the asker means "what type of controls do I need to use to create a user interface like Microsoft Office, and where can I obtain them?" Whether (s)he knows it yet or not.

Comment: What sort of application are you trying to create?

Comment: @xanatos: agree , @Cody: If yes, then let him rephrase his question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) is a good place to start. Also you may checkout [this blog post](http://elegantcode.com/2009/04/07/the-free-office-wpf-ribbon/) which illustrates how to create an Office like Ribbon in WPF.

Answer (score 1):

There are many rich controls collections, some free, some that need payment (devexpress.com for example).

You want it for WinForms, for Silverlight, for WPF, for ASP.NET? (devexpress has all of them).

If you want something "free", there are toolkits for [WPF](http://wpf.codeplex.com/) and [Silverlight](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/) on codeplex.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to emulate the Office 2007/2010 [ribbon](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/use-the-ribbon-HA010089895.aspx)?

Codeplex has a WinForms ribbon control you might like at http://ribbon.codeplex.com/.

See also [Ribbon UI Control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Krypton - It is a Free Winforms Skinner (Themer) that gives a cool look without  too much effort. All you need to do is use their controls (which are extended from the basic Winforms Controls and have the same properties / methods  events.

Answer (score 0):

The visual part of Office that I see most people emulating is the ribbon control.  Here's info on an example like it.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ribboncontrol.aspx