# create windows application with Ribbons

Tags: c#, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ribbon UI Control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)

I am just trying to create a windows application which will have a toolbars similar to 
ms-office 2007 . 
can Anyone help me where to start with ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this question for Winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)

[See this for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2bfc3187-74aa-4154-a670-76ef8bc2a0b4&displaylang=en)

**EDIT**

If you really want to develop the ribbon yourself you have to realize that it will take a lot of effort.

There are two main reasons that it will cost you a lot of work.

1. Microsoft has a patent (pending?) on the looks and functionality of the ribbon. They are willing to allow you to build your own BUT you'll have to [stick to their guidelines and you have to sign a license that you will do that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/aa973809.aspx).
2. The users will expect the ribbon to be the same too and [the sheer amount of features is enormous.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc872782.aspx)

All in all a lot of work. But if it is to learn from it might be worth it. For production code I'd pick a Microsoft implementation.

Comment: Hi Erno,
Is There any way to develop those ribbon controls myself (for my c# application)
Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: @Karthik_sirpi, I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[you can use devexpress ribbon control](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Bars/)

Answer (score 1):

You may install Dotnetbar and has all that you need.

It has all the `Office2007` looking controls such as `LabelX`, `MessageBoxX` etc. (for C# `Labe`l, `MessageBox` etc. respectively) to `RibbonBar`, `RibbonPanel` etc.