# Ribbon control for .NET Windows Forms Application

Tags: .net, winforms, controls, ribbon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ribbon UI Control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)

Is there any reliable Ribbon control for Windows Forms application (free or not too expensive one)? I know a bunch of them for WPF, but not for the Window Forms.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/toolbars/RibbonLocalization.aspx

Comment: This approach requires Windows 7, which is not very good.

Answer (score 3):

Is this the kind of thing you are after:

http://ribbon.codeplex.com/

I used this (or something very similar) in the past to get ribbons on my non-wpf .NET applications.  It is open source.

Hope this helps

Comment: It is on the Beta stage. Designer is not supported. I hoped, there were more mature projects. And buying, for exapmle Krypton ribbon is too expensive. So, the question is still open.