# How to implement a toolbar similar to microsoft word 2007 using C# (windows forms)?

Tags: c#, .net, windows-forms-designer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ribbon UI Control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)

I have a requirement to implement a toolbar similar to microsoft word 2007 using C#.

Actualy I need not implement ribbon control. I just have to implement a similar toolbar that is shown when we click on the tab of the ribbon. Just like grouping some common buttons/controls together (some buttons arranged in horizontal and some in vertical)

How can we do it ?

Comment: please donot make it as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

try whit Ribbon control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386198(v=vs.90).aspx

http://ribbon.codeplex.com/

If you use Wpf follow this example

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/ribboncontrol.aspx

Regards

Comment: Actualy I need not implement ribbon control. I just have to implement a similar toolbar that is shown when we click on the tab of the ribbon. Just like grouping some common buttons/controls together (some buttons arranged in horizontal and some in vertical)