# Is there no Windows Form Ribbon Control?

Tags: c#, .net, ribbon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ribbon UI Control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)

I am using an older windows frams application.

A Task is to Update it to .net 4.0 and the use of ribbons.

But as i aks Mr. G there is no such thing than a native Ribbon for Windows Forms.

Yes i know you can wrap it but that is not doable.

Is there / will there be a ribbon for windows forms?

thank you!