# Windows 8 RibbonBar control for .NET WinForms Apps?

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-8

Will Windows 8 provide a ready to use RibbonBar control for .NET WinForms applications?

Comment: This question doesn't really make a lot of sense: if at all, it will be provided by some version of the .NET framework (unless you P/Invoke).

Comment: you might get answer here,http://superuser.com/

Comment: @FasteKerinns: it's a programming question. StackOverflow is a better place that super user.

Comment: Oaky, Actually I have no idea about .Net so cant confirm that but that's why written you might get,and i see that this question is not accepted by the .net dev here and got 3 close vote..so advice if its missing the other site for software..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the ribbon bar makes use of all the WPF classes and XMAL. So it's probably not support in WinForms.

MSDN Documentation: 
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Here is an open source implementation of the ribbon:

http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/

Similar question:
[Ribbon UI Control for WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413910/ribbon-ui-control-for-winforms)