# how to create ribbon like windows 8 explorer in windows form application

Tags: winforms, windows-8, ribbon

i am beginner for win-forms and i was searching on Google last 2 days . i want that type of ribbon in windows form application file,computer,view etc.

[image: see this screenshot. i want that type of ribbon in windows form application file,computer,view etc.]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows 8 RibbonBar control for .NET WinForms Apps?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011442/windows-8-ribbonbar-control-for-net-winforms-apps)

Comment: but this one solution is for WPF. not for winforms

Comment: That question is for winforms only. It has links to another winforms questions also.

Comment: and this link is not opening in my pc.http://windowsribbon.codeplex.com/

Comment: That works fine for me. Check https://isitup.org/windowsribbon.codeplex.com

Comment: ya its up but not opening in my computer. and also codeplex.com not opening

Comment: ok. got it using proxysite

Comment: cant download that tool cause of proxy-site. can u please give another link of that tool?. or any other suggestion for that type of bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many commercial ribbon controls for WinForms out there for example from DevExpress, Janusys.